# Zero of $x^2 + 1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x] / \langle (x^2 + 1)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> Let $f(x)$ = $x^2 + 1$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Clearly, $f$ has no zeroes in this ring. Construct an extension field $E$ in which $f$ has a zero.

The answer is $\mathbb{Q}[x] / \langle (x^2 + 1)\rangle$. But I don't really quite see what the zero is, or how to construct a zero.

Really, any help on this would be tremendously helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to check that there is an element $\alpha = p(x) + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle\in E$ such that $\alpha^2 + (1 + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle) = 0 + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle$. Let $\alpha = x + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle$. Then
$$
\alpha^2 + (1 + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle) = (x + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle)^2 + (1 + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle) = (x^2 + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle) + (1 + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle) = (x^2 + 1) + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle = 0 + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Isn't this the same as mine

Comment: @learnmore as the OP was rather confused by the answer as given to them, I wanted to give more details on the computation, as they might have also been confused on how to work with elements in the quotient ring.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was confused about, thank you for the explanation! Side question: would $F[x]$ / <($f(x)$> always be an extension field that contains a zero for some polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$?

Comment: @Max No, you need $f$ to be irreducible over your field $F$, otherwise $F[x]/(f)$ will not be a field at all. If $f$ is irreducible, then $K = F[x]/(f)$ will be a field and have an element $a$ satisfying $f(a) = 0$; namely, $a = x + (f)$. Note also that not every extension field has this property: in particular, the degree of the extension $F[x]/(f)$ over $F$ has degree equal to the degree of $f$, and so must be finite.

Answer (score 4):

Check for :

$x+\langle x^2+1\rangle$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the image of x, under the natural map from Q[X] to Q[X]/ . That is your root of the polynomial.